# setEndDate() in smartgwt

Tags: date, smartgwt

I have a requirement to prevent the user from selecting date which is greater than current date. I tried to enforce it by setting setEndDate(new Date()) but it didn't work.

```
DateItem dateItem = new DateItem();  

dateItem.setTitle("Date"); 
dateItem.setName("dateValue");
dateItem.setUseTextField(true);

TextItem textItem = new TextItem();
textItem.setAttribute("readOnly", true);

dateItem.setAttribute("textFieldProperties", textItem); 
dateItem.setDisabled(true);
dateItem.setRequiredMessage("Please select a valid Date");
dateItem.setEndDate(new Date());
```

Even now I am able to select dates 19/5/2011, 20/5/2011 and so on.

Comment: Edited my previous post. Most of the java classes are not available to the smart gwt compiler at compile time. for instance, i am trying to use java.util.Calendar class as most of the date class methods are deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well according to the documentation, `dateItem.setStartDate()` or `dateItem.setEndDate()` does not prevent the user to select an invalid date. You may read it from [here](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/DateItem.html#getStartDate%28%29).

Hope this helps you.

Comment: `DateRangeValidator drv = new DateRangeValidator();        drv.setMax(new Date());
dateItem.setValidators(drv);'` This gets validated when the form is submitted.. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an event onchanged which puts the current date instead of whatever the user wrote in the date field if he entered a greater date.

Comment: This should probably be a comment.